# Rename primitive data types globally?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I would like to be able to write `int32` instead of `int` and `uint64` instead of `unsigned __int64`. I can accomplish this using `typedef`s by creating a file named `PrimitiveTypes.h`.

```
typedef signed char int8;
typedef signed short int16;
typedef signed int int32;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef __int64 int64;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
```

Now I can include `PrimitiveTypes.h` in every file that needs to use primitives, which turns out to be very close to every single file.

Perhaps this is bad practice, but is there a way add the re-definitions globally so I don't have to manually include the new primitives in every single file, or perhaps another solution to the problem? I'm using Visual Studio, in case there is any specific solutions.

Comment: Visual Studio uses `stdafx.h` for common includes if I'm not mistaking, so you might as well include your header there.

Comment: Concur, especially since your `primitivetypes.h` is not likely to change much once you've defined your types.

Comment: That would make it a little bit more convenient, but I would still need to include `primitivetypes.h` in every header file, as I don't think including a large `stdafx.h` in a header file is a good idea if trying to reduce compilation time.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Visual Studio uses whatever you think appropriate. `stdafx.h` is just a convention. On larger solutions, I will use different headers for different projects - I wouldn't want a database header in the GUI layer or vice versa.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for the clarification. I don't use Visual Studio for C++, so I didn't know it was possible to have multiple headers like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `/FI` switch which Force Includes a header before the first line of code.

But ordinarily you'd just put it in the precompiled header. You mention in the comments that a big precompiled header is a bad idea. It's in fact the other way around. A large set of non-precompiled headers is a bad idea. You want as much precompiled as possible, even though most files won't need the full set.

Comment: `Force Include`, worked great for my purpose, thanks! :) I suspected there would be a similar solution, but when I seached for "automatic includes" and "implicit includes" I couldn't find anything. I understand it can be really confusing to read code if a lot of compiler magic is happening behind the scene (such as hidden includes), but as long as stick to obvious changes, such as own data types, I think it should be fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't think a big precompiled headers is a bad idea. Although from what I understand they are only supposed to be included in `.cpp`. In `.h` files you should try to avoid includes and instead prefer forward declarations. Including a big precompiled header in every `.h` seems like a mistake, and only including the much smaller `PrimitiveTypes.h` seemed like a better idea (which I don't have to manually do thanks to your suggestion).

Answer (score 2):

In standard c++ we have the [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) header for this.
Just say

```
#include <cstdint>
```

For older standards you can usually rely on

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

And yes you will have to include it at every file where you use these types. You may have a project central header file though, that is included everywhere anyway.

Comment: Ah, good to know it's in the standard. Although I'm probably a bit to lazy to type the extra `_t` every time, even though it's common practice to do so.

Comment: @Adelost To write portable code I would highly recommend to spend the extra efforts and write those additional `_t`. Doesn't your IDE do this for you?